# Find inverse with different restricted domains

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am supposed to find the inverse, if possible, to the following function:

$$f(x)=3-e^{2x}+3e^{x}$$

Firstly if the domain is $D=(-\infty,0]$ and secondly if the domain is $D=[0,\infty)$. My attempts at proving the functions has an inverse by using a contrapositive proof for the inverse has been futile. So I've attempted to find the inverse by solving for x and then changing arguments. I then found that the inverse should be

$$f^{-1}(x)=ln(\frac{3}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{21}{4}-x})$$

This yields two inverses not taking into account the two different domains, however I am stuck as how I shall find if there is an inverse function in the respective domains. I know the function is supposed to have an inverse in the first domain but and not in the second, but why?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ghdvtocqot

Comment: your function is not monotonously

Comment: @Khosrotash I am supposed to answer by hand, thus I cannot draw it.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I see, but I have had a hard time proving that, and even if that is given, I don't know why the inverse only exists in one of the domains and not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In domain $D=(-\infty,0]$ you have $x=0 \to y=5 $ so $(0,5)$ must work in $f^{-1}$ and you can choose one of sign $\pm $
$$f^{-1}(x)=ln(\frac{3}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{21}{4}-x})\\put \space  (5,0) \\ 0=ln(\frac{3}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{21}{4}-5}) \space  ?\\
0=ln(\frac{3}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}})\\
0=ln(\frac{3}{2}\pm \frac{1}{2})\\$$here  $-$ work $0=ln(\frac{3-1}{2}) \checkmark\\$
so
In domain $D=(-\infty,0] \to f^{-1}(x)=ln(\frac{3}{2}- \sqrt{\frac{21}{4}-x})$
  but in $D=[0,\infty)$ has a relative maxima , so $f(x)$ is not one to one function ,and does not had an inverse .

you can do also for domain $D=[0,\infty)$